# Can't find symbols in stdint.h

Tags: c++, cstdint, apportable

When I used Apportable for my C++ source code, It cannot find symbols defined in `stdint.h`.

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'UINT8_MAX'
```

The code worked well with Xcode, and this error raised only on Apportable. I added `#include <cstdint>`, but it was no effect.

Here's my current `.cpp` file.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include "Pixel.h"

namespace
Eonil
{
    namespace
    Graphics
    {
        using namespace std;

        Pixel::Pixel(glm::vec4 const vector)
        {
            r   =   vector.r * ((Scalar)UINT8_MAX);
            g   =   vector.g * ((Scalar)UINT8_MAX);
            b   =   vector.b * ((Scalar)UINT8_MAX);
            a   =   vector.a * ((Scalar)UINT8_MAX);
        }

        glm::vec4 const
        Pixel::vector() const
        {
            return  glm::vec4(((Scalar)r) / ((Scalar)UINT8_MAX),
                              ((Scalar)g) / ((Scalar)UINT8_MAX),
                              ((Scalar)b) / ((Scalar)UINT8_MAX),
                              ((Scalar)a) / ((Scalar)UINT8_MAX));
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Take this to the devs. Probably just macros they haven't added yet, cause there's so many of them. Or #undef and #define it yourself.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Currently I work around this using undef/define,  but I think I have to bring this to devs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macros are available when __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS is defined (additionally __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS seems to be missing as well). This is probably incorrectly gated or missing when compiling c++. Objective-C and C pick up on these defines for UINT8_MAX and accompanying macros. For now you can define both of those macros globally and it should have no ill effects on your project.